# Excel 2007 adding a percentage increase

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Value = 20 is a constant number

Percentage increase to "Value" in levels of 2%, 4%, 5% up to 20%

I would like to enter in a cell the `LEVEL` of the object and it return the `VALUE + the percentage increase`.

```
Entering 1 return 20
Entering 2 returns 20+2%
Entering 3 returns 20+4%
```

The returned level is used in another calculation in a another cell such as

```
20+4% X 25 Units
```

As it is now each time the percentage goes up I have to adjust the formula. I'l like to be able to just enter the level and have it automatically adjust to the required increase. A dropdown menu would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in the workbook, you should create a two-column table that relates your numerical input to a % increase.

Once you've created the table, you can refer to it in your formulas by using the `VLOOKUP` function. For instance, where your value is in `A1`, the numerical input is in `B1`, and the table is in `E2:F6`, you would use the formula

```
=A1*(1+VLOOKUP(B1,$E$2:$F$6,2,FALSE))
```

The `VLOOKUP` here will look up the value of `B1` in the first column of the table and return the associated increase value in the second column of the table.

[image]

As for implementing a drop-down menu for the numerical input, you can do that using Excel's Data Validation feature (on the Data ribbon). Just choose to allow a List and use the first column of the lookup table as the data.

Comment: In case that "5%" is a typo, `=A1*(1+(B1-1)*0.02)` should work.

Comment: @Scott The OP included 5% in the list of values. It looks like there isn't a regular rule, based on that.

Comment: Ok I tried to post a screen of the sheet no enough points.. The formula I tried to use

=A9*(1+VLOOKUP(L8,$A$2:$F$40,2,FALSE))

Not working.. Cells used and values below

B9 is the static value of 20
the A19 B19 sections is the Value steps such as

A19 = 1  B19 = .02
A20 = 2  B20 = .04
A21 = 3  B21 = .60
etc downwards

L8 is where you enter a value from A20-A32 ( in reality down to A40)
1 or 2 or 3 etc to 20

The associated increase percentage should be output to cell C9


Thanks for all the replies

Ok so I tried to post an image and cant, SO editing Cell Info as best I can to explain

Comment: @Scott hope this helps explain my issue thanks for answering

Comment: @Excellll Thanks for the responce yes the 5% is a typo should increase 2% each value, but from level 19-20 is a 4% increase for a total of a 40% increase at level 20